# How to change the ReadOnly DataNode to normal status after clearing the disk space for Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I checked the previous questions and know that if the DataNode of Apache IoTDB switched to `ReadOnly` mode, this is because the disk space is full. I want to know after I free up the disk space, how can I restore the IoTDB DataNode status to normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'SET SYSTEM TO RUNNING' statement to rerun the DataNode status of Apache IoTDB.See if your DataNode status has been changed to 'Running'.